# return value for an undefined JSON object

Tags: android, json

```
JSONObject paging = (JSONObject) fulldata.get("paging");
nexting=(String) paging.get("next");
```

What will be the value in nexting if there is no object with name next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will throw an exception if the key does not exist, and so it will contains the initialization value. You could use the opt* method that never thrown an exception and will return a default value' For instance:

```
nexting = paging.optString("next");
if (nexting != null) {
}
```

or

```
nexting = paging.optString("next", "fallback");
if (!"fallback".equals(nexting)) {
}
```

another thing you could do, is to check if the json contains the string:

```
if (paging.has("next")) {

}
```